# NullPointer reference sending message on RabbitMQ transport

Tags: wso2, rabbitmq, esb

When sending from ESB 4.9.0 API to RabbitMQ with this transport string:

```
<send>
    <endpoint>
        <address name="scalehouse_001_rabbitmq" trace="enable" uri="rabbitmq:/ScaleHouses?rabbitmq.server.host.name=localhost&amp;rabbitmq.server.port=5672&amp;rabbitmq.server.user.name=guest&amp;rabbitmq.server.password=guest&amp;rabbitmq.queue.name=scalehouse_001"/>
    </endpoint>
  </send>
```

I get this error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException at org.apache.axis2.transport.rabbitmq.RabbitMQMessage.&lt;init&gt;(RabbitMQMessage.java:43) at org.apache.axis2.transport.rabbitmq.RabbitMQSender.sendOverAMQP(RabbitMQSender.java:84) at org.apache.axis2.transport.rabbitmq.RabbitMQSender.sendMessage(RabbitMQSender.java:72) at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.AbstractTransportSender.invoke(AbstractTransportSender.java:112) at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:442) at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.DynamicAxisOperation$DynamicOperationClient.send(DynamicAxisOperation.java:185) at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.DynamicAxisOperation$DynamicOperationClient.executeImpl(DynamicAxisOperation.java:167) at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:149) at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2FlexibleMEPClient.send(Axis2FlexibleMEPClient.java:542) at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2Sender.sendOn(Axis2Sender.java:79)
```

Does anyone have experience with RabbitMQ transport, and can provide insight into potential causes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue is in your axis2.xml configuration. Please follow the below steps.

under the transport receivers section in axis2.xml, find the rabbitmq transport receiver and replace it with your configuration. A sample configuration is given here to help you.

```
<transportReceiver name="rabbitmq" class="org.apache.axis2.transport.rabbitmq.RabbitMQListener">
    <parameter name="AMQPConnectionFactory" locked="false">
        <parameter name="rabbitmq.server.host.name" locked="false">localhost</parameter>
        <parameter name="rabbitmq.server.port" locked="false">5672</parameter>
        <parameter name="rabbitmq.server.user.name" locked="false">guest</parameter>
        <parameter name="rabbitmq.server.password" locked="false">guest</parameter>
        <parameter name="rabbitmq.connection.retry.interval" locked="false">10000</parameter>
        <parameter name="rabbitmq.connection.retry.count" locked="false">5</parameter>
    </parameter>
</transportReceiver>
```

From above configuration WSO2 ESB can act as a RabbitMQ consumer. Then locate the transport sender element in axis2.xml for the rabbitmq and uncomment it. A sample configuration for rabbitmq sender is given below.

```
<transportSender name="rabbitmq" class="org.apache.axis2.transport.rabbitmq.RabbitMQSender"/>
```

After applying this line of code, WSO2 ESB can act as  a RabbitMQ producer where it can produce messages to a given RabbitMQ queue or topic.

For more on this you can find here.

http://ravindraranwala.blogspot.com/2015/09/rabbitmq-transport-in-wso2-esb.html